# $d(A,B\cup C)\leq \max\{d(A,B),d(A,C)\}+\log 2$ for additive sets $A,B,C$

Tags: co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics

> Suppose that $A,B$ are additive sets in $Z$. Show that $d(A,B\cup
>  C)\leq \max\{d(A,B), d(A,C)\}+\log 2.$

Suppose that $d(A,B)\leq d(A,C),$ then we need to show that $d(A,B\cup C)\leq d(A,C)+\log 2.$ It is equivalent to the following statement: if $|A-B||C|^{1/2}\leq |A-C||B|^{1/2},$ then $|A-B\cup C||C|^{1/2}\leq 2|A-C||B\cup C|^{1/2}.$

This was my approach: we see that $|A-B\cup C||B|\leq |A-B||B\cup C-B|$ by Ruzsa triangle inequality and $|A-B|\leq \dfrac{|A-C||B|^{1/2}}{|C|^{1/2}}.$ Hence $$|A-B\cup C|\leq \dfrac{|A-B||B\cup C-B|}{|B|}\leq \dfrac{|A-C||B|^{1/2}|B\cup C-B|}{|B||C|^{1/2}}.$$ I thought that if we can show that $|B\cup C-B|\leq 2|B\cup C|^{1/2}|B|^{1/2}$ then we are done. But I realized that this inequality is false. Also constant $2$ on the RHS bothers me  because I have no idea where it comes from.

Thanks a lot for your help!

**Remark:** I realize this is not a research level problem and can be asked at MSE, but I have asked these questions there a couple of times and have not received any answers.

Comment: Can not we just bound $|A-B\cup C|\leqslant |A-B|+|A-C|$?

Comment: @FedorPetrov, First of all thanks a lot for your comment! So let's try to use the bound which you wrote $|A-B\cup C|\leq |A-B|+|A-C|.$ Suppose that $d(A,B)\leq d(A,C)\Leftrightarrow \dfrac{|A-B|}{|A-C|}\leq \dfrac{|B|^{1/2}}{|C|^{1/2}}$, then we need to show that $d(A,B\cup C)\leq d(A,C)+\log 2 \Leftrightarrow \dfrac{|A-B\cup C|}{|A-C|}\leq \dfrac{2|B\cup C|^{1/2}}{|C|^{1/2}}.$ Let's try to show that: $\dfrac{|A-B\cup C|}{|A-C|}\leq \dfrac{|A-B|}{|A-C|}+1\leq \dfrac{|B|^{1/2}}{|C|^{1/2}}+1.$

Comment: From $|A-B||C|^{1/2}\leq |A-C||B|^{1/2}$ and $|A-B\cup C|\leq |A-B|+|A-C|$, one obtains $|A-B\cup C||C|^{1/2}\leq (|B|^{1/2}+|C|^{1/2})|A-C|$. This is enough for your "equivalent statement".

Comment: @GabeConant, you can see I already wrote this inequality: $|A-B\cup C||C|^{1/2}\leq (|B|^{1/2}+|C|^{1/2})|A-C|.$ In order to finish that we need to show that $|B|^{1/2}+|C|^{1/2}\leq 2|B\cup C|^{1/2}$. However, this one is quite obvious since it can be separated into two cases: $|B|\leq |C|$ and $|C|\leq |B|$. QED

Comment: @FedorPetrov, thank you so much for your helpful comment!